# Alarm app stopped working if someone calls

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, alarm

When my alarm rings, if I immediately receive a call, my alarm stops !

This scenario doesn't make sense to me !

Do I have to use another alternative alarm apps? If so, what would you recommend ?

Comment: does it make sense that a call you’re potentially answering being interrupted by an alarm?

Comment: Why would the alarm stops at all if I didn't answer the call?

Comment: And the phone is supposed to know this how, exactly?  Is the alarm permanently stopped or just snoozed?

Comment: Permanently stopped.

Comment: I figured a way to solve my problem. 1) schedule " do not disturb " 2) phone calls won't come while the alarm is ringing. I'll try that tonight.